# Кнопка Floating Action Button

Tags: android

Я слышал что главной функцией Floating Action Button - отражать только главное действие в приложении.
Вопрос: Можно ли использовать три FAB в своем приложении, если ДА, то как реализовать?

Comment: в чем проблема добавить на разметку нужное количество кнопок? или о чем вы вообще спрашиваете

Comment: Если добавлю, то это не будет как неправильное (или как это еще называют) использование компонентов, ну по Гайдлайном имею ввиду!

Comment: FAB - неотъемлемый элемент Material Design,но всеже гайдлайны это не свод жестких и узких рамок, а в каком направлении желательно делать, дабы приложения имели примерно одинаковый стиль. Если вы добавите несколько кнопок, то ничего страшного не случится, и никто вам пальцем тыкать не будет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Гугл говорит о том, что на один экран - одна кнопка.
2. Поместить больше на экран можно, `FAB` это просто `View` - располагайте его где хотите в разметке. Но юзеры будут ожидать лишь одну кнопку и начнут путаться и это может лишить ваше приложение шанса фичеринга как не следующее гайдлайнам.